# What does “the bully pulpit has splintered” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The article of New York Times (April 29) written by a former White House speechwriter, David Litt under the headline,” What it’s like to write jokes for President Obama” wraps up with the following paragraph:

> “But I do think that presidential comedy has played a role in this
>   chapter in American history. **The bully pulpit has splintered**. It’s
>   become harder than ever to get people’s attention. And the White House
>   has recognized what class clowns have known all along. Being funny
>   helps.”
>   http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/30/opinion/what-its-like-to-write-jokes-for-president-obama.html?action

I’m not clear with the phrase, “The bully pulpit has splintered.” Though I know the meanings of individual word of “bully,” “pulpit” and “splinter,” I’m unable to associate them with the concept of the meaningful set of a phrase.

Why is the President's speach stage a "bully" pulpit? Can you translate it into a plain and simpler phrase?

Comment: A bully pulpit is the perquisite of a leader, who by virtue of the importance of his office has the attention and respect of a wide audience. What he says will be heard and absorbed. It is splintered because there are so many platforms vying for our attention these days.

Comment: Look up the idiom "bully pulpit".  Has been in and out of vogue since Teddy Roosevelt.  There should be several articles on the topic floating around the interweb.

Comment: @HotLicks Wait, did this really originate in the Bull Moose Party???

Comment: @tchrist: You can find Roosevelt using "bully pulpit" in 1909 in Google books, and the Bull Moose didn't come until after the attempted assassination of Roosevelt in 1912. [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Party_(United_States,_1912)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[Bully pulpit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bully-pulpit)*** refers to the position of power of a politician from which they exert their functions and authority. Because of technology communication nowadays is split over many different  channels and the article suggests that this makes it harder for a politician to attract people's attention.

Bully pulpit:

> - a position of authority or public visibility, especially a political office, from which one may express one's views. (Dictionary.com)

***[Origin:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bully_pulpit)***

> - ***This term was coined by President Theodore Roosevelt, who referred to the White House as a "bully pulpit", by which he meant a terrific platform from which to advocate an agenda.***
> - ***Roosevelt used the word bully as an adjective meaning "superb" or "wonderful"***, a more common usage in his time than it is today. Another expression which survives from this era is "bully for you", synonymous with "good for you". (Wikipedia)

From ***[World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-bul3.htm):***

> - Half a dozen of us were with the President [Theodore Roosevelt] in his library. He was sitting at his desk reading to us his forthcoming Message. He had just finished reading a paragraph of a distinctly ethical character when he suddenly stopped, swung round in his swivel chair and said ***“I suppose my critics will call that preaching, but I have got such a bully pulpit!”***
>
>   - Lyman Abbott, in The Outlook, 27 Feb. 1909. Dr Abbott, a notable Protestant theologian and author, was editor-in-chief of the magazine. ***The anecdote was thought worth repeating in the New York Times on 6 March. Roosevelt was fond of bully as an adjective; when he returned to the US following his successful campaign in Cuba in 1898, he said “I’ve had a bully time and a bully fight!”***